# Reinitialize waypoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

So I'm trying to work on the super thin documentation of this plugin http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Pretty simple stuff, everytime my footer is in view, I fetch new elements via ajax and append them. Except once a waypoint has been hit once, it won't run again, what am I doing wrong?

```
        $('#footer').waypoint(function (direction) {
                   var $appender = $('.more_timeline').last();
            var data = {};
            var $wrapper = $('.container');
            var $yearwrapper = $wrapper.find('.year').last();
            data.current_year = $yearwrapper.find('.year_timeline').html();
            var $monthwrapper = $wrapper.find('.month').last();
            data.current_month = $monthwrapper.find('.month_timeline').attr('month-key');
            data.offset = $('.time_offset').last().attr('offset');

            console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: data,
                url: 'jquery/wiki/extendtimeline',
                success: function (response) {
                    $appender.after(response);
                    $appender.hide();

                }
            });

        }, {
            offset: '100%'
        })
```

Can be seen live:
http://kaboodle.io/u/calbert/timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waypoint save the position of your footer when you load the page. The position of the waypoint isn't recalculated when you scrolled to his position (on the first ajax call).

You will have to recreate the waypoint or update it each time you reach it and you make your ajax Call..

In fact, you will see that, if you first scroll, than return to top page and rescroll on the previous footer position, it will load the next content.

Try using

```
$('#footer').waypoint('destroy') — Unregister waypoints and unbind all handlers.
$('#footer').waypoint('remove') — Unregister waypoints but leave handlers intact.
```

Make a function that set the waypoint and one that unsetter it. 
When you do your AJAX call, you just have to call the unsetter and than the set again. and all should be fine :)

Try This :

```
// JavaScript source code
var footer = $('#footer');
footer.waypoint(getNextFilms, {
    offset: '100%'
})

function getNextFilms(direction) {
    var $appender = $('.more_timeline').last();
    var data = {};
    var $wrapper = $('.container');
    var $yearwrapper = $wrapper.find('.year').last();
    data.current_year = $yearwrapper.find('.year_timeline').html();
    var $monthwrapper = $wrapper.find('.month').last();
    data.current_month = $monthwrapper.find('.month_timeline').attr('month-key');
    data.offset = $('.time_offset').last().attr('offset');

    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        url: 'jquery/wiki/extendtimeline',
        success: function (response) {
            $appender.after(response);
            $appender.hide();
            footer.waypoint('destroy');
            footer.waypoint(getNextFilms, {
                offset: '100%'
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought but how do I do that? Their new documentation is completely empty?

Comment: use this :

$('#footer').waypoint('destroy') or
$('#footer').waypoint('remove')

Comment: I saw the post you're quoting and remove appears to be depreciated. Destroy works fine but I still need to reinitialize it, I've tried "enable" but that won't work.

Comment: `Waypoint.refreshAll()` will recalculate trigger points on all waypoints, assuming you're using 3.x. On 2.x (which this answer seems to be using) it was `$.waypoints('refresh')`. But beware, you aren't checking for if the direction is "down". A refresh will end up triggering your footer waypoint in the "up" direction and causing another page to load.